# Md5_file() для xls файла

Tags: php, xls, md5

Здравствуйте. Нужно сравнить два файла, актуальный и сохраненный ранее (образец). Данные статические (например время туда не пишется) Для csv & txt файлов такой подход проходит, для xls нет. (Данные одни и те же). Специфика реализации xls?
Код для csv

```
$expectedHashOfFile = md5_file("exampleTestGrid.csv");
$actualHashOfFile = md5_file($this->_gridDir . "/testGrid.csv");
$this->assertEquals($expectedHashOfFile, $actualHashOfFile);
```

Comment: если md5 разная то содержимое файлов разное.

Comment: данные в файл пишутся одинаковые (как писал выше "Для csv & txt файлов такой подход проходит"). А вот содержимое экселевских файлов наверно получается разным, хотя сравнивая данные визуально разницы нет. Экселевские файлы формируются с помощью PHPExcel. Похоже когда сохраняю файл, туда попадает что то еще (с экселевскими файлами раньше не сталкивался в таком разрезе, и попадает ли в файл при сохранении какая либо служебная информация не знаю...) Если бы я например писал в качестве данных текущее время, то было бы понятно. Но я время явно не пишу.

Comment: тогда вам нужно экспортировать данные, например в csv, и сравнивать.

Comment: я "передаю дальше" одну и ту же информацию в 3 файлах: csv , txt & xls. csv & txt сравниваю с помощью md5_file()  а для xls файла пришлось написать свой костыль, сравнивающий содержимое файла по ячейкам. В чем прикол с xls я так и не понял, может после "осенит". eicto спасибо за отзывчивость :)

Comment: Word, например, показывает время правки документа... Вот есть замечание на эту тему (http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_samebutdifferent):

Two Microsoft Office (Word, Excel, PowerPoint) files may look the same, but have different file sizes, or the timestamps may change after viewing the files even though they were not changed.  Microsoft Office includes version and timestamp information in all office file formats.  It also keeps track of the time the file was last accessed.  This results in file size and binary differences even when the visible file has not changed.

Comment: The only way to deal with this is to compare the contents of the files using a rules-based comparison.  For version 2, add-on rules to compare the text contents of Office documents are on our Additional File Viewer Rules for Beyond Compare 2 page.  For version 3, this support is built-in.